# Getting an object from SQLite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I've been going through the docs for sqlite and I cannot figure out how I can return my query into an object.  I can iterate through.  Here is the code I've been playing with.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

```
    Private Sub Query(ByVal SQLString As String)
        Try
            Dim SQLiteDRObj As SQLiteDataReader
            Dim ResultsObj As DataTable = Nothing
            Dim ResultSet As DataSet = Nothing
            Dim SQLAdapter As SQLiteDataAdapter = Nothing

            Me.GetSqlConnection()
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand = New SQLiteCommand(SQLConnection)
            SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString

            'SQLAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Joes2", SQLConnection)
            'SQLAdapter.MissingMappingAction = MissingMappingAction.Ignore
            'SQLAdapter.Fill(ResultSet, "Joes2")

            SQLiteDRObj = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

            'Put the results into an object ????

            SQLiteDRObj.Close()
            SQLConnection.Close()
            SQLConnection.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

EDITED

Suppose I have a class such as this

```
Public Class Drawing
    Private _ID As Guid
    Private _DrawingDate As Date
    Private _GameID As Guid

    Public Property ID As Guid
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Guid)
            _ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DrawingDate As Date
        Get
            Return _DrawingDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _DrawingDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

and I have a table in SQLite such as this...

```
Table Name is "Drawings"
ID, DrawingDate
(SomeGuid, 2014-2-14)
(SomeGUid, 2014-2-15)
```

and now I want to load it up like this.

```
Dim Drawings as New Drawing("SELECT * From Drawings")
```

If this is the wrong approach entirely, please let me know.  I'm just trying to stick with proper OOP. (Trying to learn the right way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't specific to SQLite.  ADO.NET works basically the same no matter the provider or data source.  What exactly do you mean by "into an object"?  If you want to populate a DataTable with the result set then create one and call its Load method, passing the data reader as an argument.  If you mean that you want to create an instance of an entity class then you would use a Do or While loop, calling Read on the data reader and getting each field value by name or ordinal.

Comment: my apologies for the poor explanation.  I do not have the proper vocabulary as of yet.  I am still learning vb.net (self taught)

Comment: As I already said, you should call ExecuterReader and then use a Do or While loop to Read the data record by record.  For each record, create an instance of your class and copy the data into it from the data reader, then add it to a list.

Comment: got it thank you.  I had another issue that was preventing it from working properly.